# Crash only in Android8.0/7.0/7.1/6.0, due to libc.so (tgkill+12/abort+63)

Tags: android

I've searched on Google many times but did not find a way to locate the error code.

I'm seeing this native crash with the following stack trace.

```
    Android 8.0
    pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> package name <<<

    Case 1
    backtrace:
    #00  pc 000000000004b10c  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
    #01  pc 000000000001a9a3  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+54)
    #02  pc 0000000000006849  /system/lib/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+152)
    #03  pc 00000000000c72b7  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android6bitmap8toBitmapEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobject+34)
    #04  pc 00000000000d8003  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZL24BitmapShader_constructorP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectxS2_ii+38)
    #05  pc 0000000000a43c1b  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.graphics.BitmapShader.nativeCreate [DEDUPED]+146)
    #06  pc 0000000000a43d5d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.graphics.BitmapShader.createNativeInstance+68)
    #07  pc 0000000000a436d5  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.graphics.Shader.getNativeInstance+100)
    #08  pc 0000000000a5fcb5  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.graphics.Paint.getNativeInstance+68)
    #09  pc 000000000110ed69  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawCircle+64)
    #10  pc 000000000001abf1  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)

    Case 2
    backtrace:
    #00  pc 000000000004add4  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
    #01  pc 000000000001a6c3  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+54)
    #02  pc 00000000000065f9  /system/lib/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+152)
    #03  pc 00000000000c711f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android6bitmap8toBitmapEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobject+34)
    #04  pc 00000000000d7ec3  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZL24BitmapShader_constructorP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectxS2_ii+38)
    #05  pc 0000000000a15103  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.graphics.BitmapShader.nativeCreate [DEDUPED]+146)
    #06  pc 0000000000a15245  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.graphics.BitmapShader.createNativeInstance+68)
    #07  pc 0000000000a14bbd  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.graphics.Shader.getNativeInstance+100)
    #08  pc 0000000000a3115d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.graphics.Paint.getNativeInstance+68)
    #09  pc 0000000000a173e7  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.graphics.Canvas.drawCircle+126)
    #10  pc 0000000000023d49  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)

    Case 3
    backtrace:
    #00  pc 000000000001a39a  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+63)
    #01  pc 000000000000655d  /system/lib/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+156)
    #02  pc 00000000000c125b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::bitmap::toBitmap(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+34)
    #03  pc 00000000000d19b5  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (BitmapShader_constructor(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long long, _jobject*, int, int)+32)
    #04  pc 00000000009da043  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.graphics.BitmapShader.nativeCreate [DEDUPED]+146)
    #05  pc 00000000009da173  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.graphics.BitmapShader.createNativeInstance+66)
    #06  pc 00000000009d9bb3  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.graphics.Shader.getNativeInstance+98)
    #07  pc 00000000009f497f  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.graphics.Paint.getNativeInstance+70)
    #08  pc 0000000000ff3d51  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawCircle+64)
    #09  pc 0000000000001e4d  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)


    Android7.0/7.1
    Case 1
    backtrace:
    #00  pc 000000000004a230  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
    #01  pc 00000000000479c3  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+34)
    #02  pc 000000000001d9c5  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
    #03  pc 0000000000019511  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
    #04  pc 0000000000017150  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
    #05  pc 000000000000c687  /system/lib/libcutils.so (__android_log_assert+114)
    #06  pc 00000000000a424b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android6Bitmap15pinPixelsLockedEv+54)
    #07  pc 00000000000a4283  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android6Bitmap17refPixelRefLockedEv+34)
    #08  pc 00000000000a43b9  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android6Bitmap11getSkBitmapEP8SkBitmap+32)
    #09  pc 00000000000ad57b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
    #10  pc 00000000021f0407  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.graphics.BitmapShader.nativeCreate+114)
    #11  pc 00000000021f0349  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.graphics.BitmapShader.<init>+124)
    #12  pc 00000000000002a1  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache_8544_8544 (deleted)

    Case 2
    backtrace:
    #00  pc 000000000004a720  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
    #01  pc 0000000000047eb3  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+34)
    #02  pc 000000000001d955  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
    #03  pc 00000000000194a1  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
    #04  pc 00000000000170e4  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
    #05  pc 000000000000d6af  /vendor/lib/libcutils.so (__android_log_assert+114)
    #06  pc 00000000000a603f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android6Bitmap15pinPixelsLockedEv+54)
    #07  pc 00000000000a6077  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android6Bitmap17refPixelRefLockedEv+34)
    #08  pc 00000000000a61a5  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android6Bitmap11getSkBitmapEP8SkBitmap+48)
    #09  pc 00000000000b1237  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
    #10  pc 0000000074d013d7  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot-framework.oat

    Android 6.0
    backtrace:
    #00  pc 000000000004323c  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
    #01  pc 0000000000041e45  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+32)
    #02  pc 000000000001bb53  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
    #03  pc 0000000000018db1  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
    #04  pc 000000000001696c  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
    #05  pc 00000000000091cb  /system/lib/libcutils.so (__android_log_assert+86)
    #06  pc 0000000000090fdf  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZNK7android6Bitmap11assertValidEv+18)
    #07  pc 000000000009105b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android6Bitmap11getSkBitmapEP8SkBitmap+6)
    #08  pc 000000000009a17b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
    #09  pc 000000007269b57f  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat
```

Here's a list of devices that are effected:
[image]

1.According to Android Vitals statistics, This mainly happens in Android 8.0.A few parts occur on Android 7 & 7.1.